# select field from table in another field from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want this in mysql:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 Where Field1=searchword 
OR Field2=searchword 
OR Field3=searchword 
OR ((SELECT filedx FROM Table2 WHERE fieldxx = Field1) = searchword)
```

Where The Field1 in 2nd select is from 1st select statment.

Comment: explain your code logic in short

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but it looks like you want to match
your `searchword` against `Table1.Field2`, `Table1.Field3` and 
`Table2.filedx`. Tables are linked by `fieldxx=Field1`. In that case
you can do simple outer join:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON (fieldxx=Field1)
 WHERE
  Field1=searchword
  OR Field2=searchword
  OR Field3=searchword
  OR filedx=searchword;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. what about if i want fieldxx=field1 or field2 or field3. is this possible -> LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON (fieldxx=Field1) or LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON (fieldxx=Field2) or LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON (fieldxx=Field3)

Comment: Sure you *can* do that, but I'm not sure you get what you want that way. Correct way would be to do `LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 ON (fieldxx=Field1 OR fieldxx=Field2 OR fieldxx=Field3)`. But in that case I'd probably question your schema or approach you take on the search. But that's difficult to comment on without full table layout and more details.